# Sum up column by value and group in R

Tags: r, sum

I have a dataframe like this:

```
data <- read.table(text="group;  yr1;   yr2;    val
  a;        1945;   1946;   20
  a;        1945;   1946;   50
  a;        1947;   1948;   40
  b;        1926;   1927;   45
  b;        1927;   1928;   -10
  b;        1927;   1928;   -15 ", sep=";", header=T, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Whats the best way to sum up the column of `val` for each pair of years by group so that the result would look like the following?

```
group   yr1     yr2     val
a       1945    1946    70
a       1946    1947    40
b       1926    1927    45
b       1927    1928    -25
```

Comment: Look at `?aggregate`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `data.table` for bigger datasets

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data)[, list(val=sum(val)), by=list(group, yr1, yr2)]
#    group  yr1  yr2 val
#1:     a 1945 1946  70
#2:     a 1947 1948  40
#3:     b 1926 1927  45
#4:     b 1927 1928 -25
```

Answer (score 5):

In base R:

```
aggregate(val ~ group + yr1 + yr2, data, sum)
#  group  yr1  yr2 val
#1     b 1926 1927  45
#2     b 1927 1928 -25
#3     a 1945 1946  70
#4     a 1947 1948  40
```